# Error removing a function from a list of functions in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a small game in python using the pygame module.

I have two lists of functions :
afunc (runs at the start of loop every frame)
bfunc (runs at the end of loop every frame)

```
    def removefunction(function = None , arg = None  ,  position = None):
    '''
    remove a function which runs every frame.Either a function, arguments or
    both can be given and the function with teh arguments will be removed
    from either afuncs or bfuncs as specified. if None is specified, both functions
    will be checked for the value
    '''

    if (arg , function) == (None,None): ##If both function and argument is None, raise error
        raise LookupError

    if arg is not None and function is not None:    ##if both function and argument are given do this
        try:
            self.afuncs.remove(self.afuncs.index([function,arg]))
        except:
            try:self.bfuncs.remove(self.bfuncs.index([function,arg]))
            except:pass

    elif arg is None and function is not None:  ##if only function is given do this
        if position is 'a':
            for func in self.afuncs:
                if function is func[0]:
                    self.afuncs.remove(func)
        elif position is 'b':
            for func in self.bfuncs:
                if function is func[0]:
                    self.bfuncs.remove(func)
        elif position is None:
            try:
                for func in self.bfuncs:
                    if function is func[0]:
                        self.bfuncs.remove(func)
            except:
                try:
                    for func in self.afuncs:
                        if function is func[0]:
                            self.afuncs.remove(func)
                except:pass

    elif function is None and arg is not None:  ##if only argument is given do this
        if position is 'a':
            for func in self.afuncs:
                if arg is func[1]:
                    self.afuncs.remove(func)
        elif position is 'b':
            for func in self.bfuncs:
                if arg is func[1]:
                    self.bfuncs.remove(func)
        elif position is None:
            try:
                for func in self.bfuncs:
                    if arg is func[1]:
                        self.bfuncs.remove(func)
            except:
                try:
                    for func in self.afuncs:
                        if arg is func[1]:
                            self.afuncs.remove(func)
                except:pass
```

thats the code to remove a function from either of the list, but this doesn't seem to be working. There are no errors so i cant point out the exact problem.

this is the function that adds new functions to the  lists :

```
    def addfunction(function , arg = None  ,  position = 'b'):
    '''
    add a function which runs every frame. argument 'a' will run the 
    function after everything, argument 'b' will run the function
     before anything is updated. These functions will run independent of
     which screen is being displayed i=unless explicitly stated in the code
     '''

    if position == 'b':
        self.bfuncs.append((function , arg))
    else:
        self.afuncs.append((function, arg))
```

This is a self generated example where this doesn't work.

```
addfunction(print,'hi')  ##adding function
removefunction(print)    ##removing function
```

Comment: *"There are no errors so i cant point out the exact problem."* - then create a self-contained example that *demonstrates* the problem, including the code that creates the list with functions.

Comment: Please provide some kind of error, traceback and/or something wen can test in isolation.

Comment: Remove `try..except` and I'm sure the error(s) will appear.

Comment: @frostnational that try...except is for deciding which list to place it in. If i remove that, id get an error even if the code is correct.

Comment: @LukasGraf, I added the examples now.

Comment: @ayushjha that code is still not self-contained and is far from a minimal example. Anyone should be able to copy and paste your code and run it, without changing a single line, and see the problem.

Comment: @ayushjha also: these seem to be methods (you're referring to `self` in the code, but neither of those methods take `self` as an argument. And because of your `except: pass` everywhere you're swallowing exceptions left and right.

Comment: `except: pass` is evil, don't use it. At the very least use `except Exception as e: print "Caught {}!".format(e)`. So you know when they're happening. If exceptions are expected behavior in a few places, only catch the specific type of exception you expect to be thrown.

Comment: @dano the `except Exception as e:print('{}').format(e)` is a great idea! ill try that thanks. I think i went a bit overboard at making my code error-proof

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be your problem, but you add items to the list using

```
self.afuncs.append((function, arg))
```

and find the index to remove them using

```
self.afuncs.index([function, arg])
```

However, `(function, arg) != [function, arg]`, so the call to `index` will raise an exception, which is masked by your `except: pass` line.

On a side note, don't use `except: pass`.  Ever.  It's just a bug waiting to happen.